# Ruby rest-client 401 Unauthorized after post of data

Tags: ruby, rest-client

I'm new to using the rest-client. I know I'm missing something, but I am trying to do the following:

1. Post to a login endpoint to authenticate
2. After authentication, post csv text to another endpoint that requires a logged in user

The authentication portion is successful, however, I am getting a `401 Unauthorized` when step 2 occurs.

```
rest_client = RestClient

login_response = @global_rest_client.post(
    host + 'LOGIN ENDPOINT', 
    { userName: 'user', password: 'password'},
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
)

import_response = rest_client.post(
        host + 'IMPORT DATA ENDPOINT',
        headers: { 'X-System-Name': 'AndroidMobile', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data },
        csv: csv_string
    )
```

My understanding of how authentication works could be wrong. My assumption is that as long as the same instance of the client has a successful login, then the post of csv data would also be successful.

I appreciate any input.

Comment: What does `login_response` look like?

Comment: Something similar to the following: `{"success":{"url": HOST ,”user":{"username”:”user”,”isAuthenticated":true,"isSecure":true,"isRecognized":true,"authExpiry": …`

Comment: does it include a token of some sort?

Comment: it returns session data, which appears to include a token

Answer (score 0):

HTTP (1.1) is stateless so a request does not contain any information about previous requests unless that information is encoded and added to the request  in some way (e.g. cookies or headers). So when you make your import request the server does not know if/that you are authenticated even though you just made a login request.

You'll have to include the token you receive from your login request in subsequent requests. This should go in the 'Authorization' header.

For example:

```
auth_token = login_response["success"]["token"] # or whatever the key is for the token

import_response = rest_client.post(
    host + 'IMPORT DATA ENDPOINT',
    headers: { 'Authorization': "Bearer #{auth_token}", 'X-System-Name': 'AndroidMobile', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data },
    csv: csv_string
)
```

The way authentication works depends on the server and can be different in different cases. So the site you are accessing might expect the Authorization header to be like `"Token #{auth_token}"` or anything else, but they should mention it in their documentation.